What was that early 1990s near-future dystopian novel with red corporate currency competing against green US government currency?
In the early 90s (1991-1993) I read a (then) near-future dystopian novel that I would like to identify so I can read it again.
The book was a soft-cover, a full novel set in the United States (set circa 2000-2010, I think). Probably published between 1989-1991). The cover was black with neon pink (graffiti-style or neon sign) writing for the title. Male author, I think.
Some unique elements I recall:

Old US government-issued currency ("green bills") vs. new corporate currency ("red bills"), usually in twenties or hundreds. Green bills were generally used for illicit transactions on the street and by the under-class. Red bills were used (required) for many common transactions. Many people refused to exchange their green currency for red, even though it had less legitimate buying power. I recall it was a trust issue, and that the red currency was issued by a corporation, replacing the green government currency. Transactions might be in green hundreds or red twenties or red fives (e.g., "that'll cost you a red five or a green hundred"). I think people would be reluctant to let go of green currency but I might have that backward.
Prolific use of street drugs (in pill form pushed by pharma corporations IIRC) to change gender and ethnicity, with many people on the street transitioning in one direction or the other, with some going back and forth looking for happiness in a world where there is none. Exact phrasing depicted two people sitting on a curb, one transitioning either from male to female or the other way around, the other transitioning from white to black or the other way around.
Toward the end of the first chapter, a TV commercial selling happiness depicting "a naked girl bouncing on a pogo stick" - the exact phrase as written IIRC.

I don't recall the precise plot of the book, but it had something to do with one corporation or cabal replacing the United States government. It had a dark, gritty tone and maybe some noir investigation elements with a male private detective as the main character. It had a very corporate-ruled theme. It was very urban - this was a city-only novel, maybe a bit cyberpunk, which would date it after Neuromancer (1986), and quite likely inspired by it in some aspects, not neccesarily the tech but the general feel of Neuromancer's Chiba city. There was a confrontation involving the main character in a corporate executive office.
Less certain details that I may not be recalling accurately:

There may have been a female supporting character from the underclass, not necessarily a love interest.
Green hundreds were used to buy information about a corporation from a shady character. Most transactioms involved a stressful decision by the buyer regarding which bills to use (i.e. the buyer was always getting ripped off one way or another, as if each transaction was devaluing their old currency while legitimizing the corporate currency).

I've been scanning through the Wikipedia Dystopian Fiction Novels category looking for titles that look familiar, and Good News sounded about right for the title. Unfortunately, the western setting seems wrong. But I think the title was something like that. Two words, not super complicated.
Update: I found an excerpt of the novel with a Google Books advanced search, but the link leads to the wrong source. Here is a screenshot of the search result:

I'm starting to think that I might have two different books conflated, as the above quote looks like it might be from a short fiction collection.

Effinger's When Gravity Fails (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Gravity_Fails) has street drugs for sex and personality changes, and a cyberpunk/dystopian air.  Haven't found a reference about the "red bills"

Doesn't look like a pogo stick mention either: https://archive.org/details/whengravityfails00effi/mode/2up?q=pogo

@Andrew Good find, and thanks for the attempt. When Gravity Fails is set in the Middle East. The book I'm looking for was set in the United States.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

@Valorum Thank you for the list. I just added a few more details. I'll continue to revise if I think of anything else.

@Parker - You've put "red bills" and "green bills" in quote marks. Are these the precise words used in the novel?

@Valorum I think the term "red bills" may have been used in a few places, but the phrase "red twenty" and "green hundred" were used in specific transactions, I just don't recall which currency was worth more, so I may have the values backwards. That was definitely important to the story and introduced in the early chapters.

Also in Nebula Awards 23, where the winners are on https://nebulas.sfwa.org/award-year/1989/

Good News from Outer Space by John Kessel


In 1999, George Eberhart, a tabloid journalist, has been resuscitated from a suicide by a new scientific process, known as the "Han process". Amidst premillennial hysteria across the United States, compounded by both biblical prophecies concerning the End of Times and Ufologists reporting sightings of giant alien spacecraft.
The resurrected George leaves both his job and his wife, Lucy, and discovers in Raleigh, North Carolina a series of unusual incidents the locals believe are angelic interventions, but that George suspects are due to alien interference with the progress of humanity.

Quotes:

Sandy had taken his withdrawal in new currency. He pulled the wad of bills out of his shirt pocket and laid a red one hundred, a third of all the money he owned in the world, on the bar. Leon regarded him coolly. Dutch snorted. "Gonna pull down your batting average, boy."

....

A naked woman on a pink neon pogo stick, insistent synthesized drums of the Wild Seeds:

Your Google Books image showed that it was in Nebula Awards 23, so I searched for the nominees that year and clicked through the novel entries. The Internet Archive has a copy to borrow, from whence I got the quotes.

Yes, this is it!! Excellent work! I was starting to second-guess my memory.

Glad to hear. I'm sure you've had the same experience I did last night, where pogo stick  search queries involving nude women turned up some... rather dodgy items.

Hah, sorry for that inconvenience! I was on my phone at a work conference, so I made sure my searches were strictly limited to book results. It's no wonder that one passage stuck in my then-teenage mind for over 30 years. I can't believe I didn't remember the alien subplot.

Also to note, the book cover you included was the same edition as the one I owned. It was used for that hardcover and softcover edition, but there are at least two other covers (I think the Internet Archive copy might be the UK edition).

:) I grabbed that one in part because it matched the "neon sign" aesthetic you mentioned.

You definitely went above and beyond. I'm really looking forward to reading this again. Just perusing the chapter titles on the Internet Archive prompted me to order an old paperback copy off of AbeBooks.
